# C# Bot Framework LUIS Intents

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I Created a chatbot using MS Bot Framework . I need to handle a intent such that for example :If user says find a item , then bot should ask the item id ", if user says find a item with id 1 or find id 1 ,then bot should not ask the item id as it is already mentioned. What is the proper way to handle these kind of scenarios?

Comment: You should have a look here before: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3):

Luis mainly consists of 2 parts - `intent` and `entity`. Intent stands for the intention of the utterance or the user text. Entities are key data in your application’s domain, here in your case one **entity** is `id`.

So first you need to train your LUIS to identity the intents and the entities. Have a look at [Create app that uses simple entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-quickstart-primary-and-secondary-data) to do the same. So here, in your case you can make a intent called `FindItem` and an entity called `id` and train it for various scenarios.

The second part is to handle the flow in code. When the luis intent is triggered, the method with that Luis intent decoration will be called, so here you need to see if the entity `id` is present in the set of entities identified; if not prompt for the same.

Your code would look like :

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("MODEL_ID", "SUBSCRIPTION_KEY")]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("FindItem")]
    public async Task FindItem(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var entities = result.Entities;
        var id = entities.First(x => x.Entity == "id");
        if ( id != null)
        {
            //Id entity is there, go ahead with your logic
        }
        else
        {
            //Id is not specified by user. Prompt for it.
            PromptDialog.Text(context, UserEnteredId, "Please enter the item id.");
        }

    }

    private async Task UserEnteredId(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        //Here message contains the id entered by user.
        //Proceed with your logic
    }

    //Rest of the logic
}
```

Comment: The id can either be number or alphabets or can be both with different string length. How to create a entity for this scenario?